# JQM annoying error loading yellow box

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

A little info..

I am busy with a JQM webapp. Backend is a custom server that has REST api, responds with XML. I use my own ajax calling the needed apis from the server (ex: getContactList,..) etc

So basically while i work, my application server is running and hooked on my DB, and i develop & test my JQM webapp local on my windows 7 PC.

Now i have a presentation later afternoon. And the annoying "ERROR LOADING PAGE" yellow box is really pissing me off. I have read somewhere that you have to transfer your site to a webserver.

How can i turn off the message completely? No yellow box, no error message.. For now i want my presentation to be clean. Later i will check on to this and maybe use more of the JQM methods...because my webapp on every site depends on $(document).ready(function()

So, please without links to JQM website i have read it but could not remove the error loading message box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide it with this css:

```
div.ui-loader.ui-overlay-shadow { display: none !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and quickest way would be to load up firebug, and inspect the element. When you know what the CSS wrapper is around the box or creating the box use the name of this css element: display:none;